application working via nodeport but not working via nginx ingress
I have an app that works properly while exposed to nodeports and doesnt when exposed to ingress.
Here what it does when it works

Request URL: http://10.11.43.11:30100/app0/public/auth
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.11.43.11:30100
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request URL: http://10.11.43.11:30100/manager/api/users/logged
Request Method: GET Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.11.43.11:30100
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Here what it does when it doesnt work
Request URL: http://10.11.43.60/app0/public/auth
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.11.43.60:80
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request URL: http://10.11.43.60/manager/api/users/logged
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 10.11.43.60:80
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin 

This is the ingress YAML
a
piVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: >-
      [{"addresses":["10.11.43.11","10.11.43.12","10.11.43.13","10.11.43.14","10.11.43.15","10.11.43.16","10.11.43.17","10.11.43.18"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"default:agata-gateway","ingressName":"default:agata-gateway-ingress","path":"/","allNodes":false},{"addresses":["10.11.43.11","10.11.43.12","10.11.43.13","10.11.43.14","10.11.43.15","10.11.43.16","10.11.43.17","10.11.43.18"],"port":80,"protocol":"HTTP","serviceName":"default:agata-gateway","ingressName":"default:agata-gateway-ingress","path":"/","allNodes":false}]
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_input_headers "Authorization: $http_authorization";
      more_set_input_headers "tgt_token: $http_tgt_token";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '60'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-cookie-path: / /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-pass-headers: JSESSIONID, tgt_token, Authorization
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '120'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '120'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: route
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
  creationTimestamp: '2024-10-26T15:39:59Z'
  generation: 1
  managedFields:
    - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-cookie-path: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-pass-headers: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: {}
        f:spec:
          f:ingressClassName: {}
          f:rules: {}
      manager: agent
      operation: Update
      time: '2024-10-26T15:40:55Z'
    - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          f:loadBalancer:
            f:ingress: {}
      manager: nginx-ingress-controller
      operation: Update
      subresource: status
      time: '2024-10-26T15:40:55Z'
  name: gateway-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: '8321604'
  uid: 5ed76945-450f-4e45-998e-ba12f203454b
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: gateway
                port:
                  number: 8000
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 10.11.43.11
      - ip: 10.11.43.12
      - ip: 10.11.43.13
      - ip: 10.11.43.14
      - ip: 10.11.43.15
      - ip: 10.11.43.16
      - ip: 10.11.43.17
      - ip: 10.11.43.18

I need it to work as per
Request URL: http://10.11.43.11:30100/app0/public/auth
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.11.43.11:30100
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request URL: http://10.11.43.11:30100/manager/api/users/logged
Request Method: GET Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.11.43.11:30100
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

I am now completely lost when it comes to what else to troubleshoot, where to look or what to modify. I need some help that would point me in the right direction and any help would be much appreciated
